# How migrate from Facebook Registration Plugin to Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, user-registration

I'm working on a site that use the **Facebook Registration Plugin** to add some custom field on registration and perform some instructions too.
It works fine, but now i'm going to update the Facebook SDK to use API v2.1 instead of actual v1.0 and Registration Plugin was removed.

Documentation says:

> This was plugin removed as of API version 2.0. It will stop working on July 30, 2015. Apps using this plugin should migrate to Facebook Login.

I'm looking the **Facebook Login** documentation but i doesn't understand how migrate from Registration to Login.

In what part of flow is better manage custom fields?

Any help is appreciated